# Evaluating a limit, $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 0^{+}} {\sum\limits_{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{t}}{1+tn^2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

It seems that the following limit exists. But I couldn't figure out the exact value. Anyone could help me? Thanks!
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^{+}} {\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{t}}{1+tn^2}}
\end{align*}

Comment: I was about to write an answer... anyway, your series can be derived from the [partial fraction series for the hyperbolic cotangent](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Coth/06/05/0001/), which leads to the limit $$\frac12\lim_{t\to 0^+} \left(\pi\coth\frac{\pi}{\sqrt t}-\sqrt t\right)$$ ... on the other hand, $\pi/2$ is the answer that I seem to be getting.

Comment: Ah, you're right J.M.; I don't think we can interchange the sum and limit here, since $\frac{\sqrt{t}}{1+tn^2}$ decays too slowly.

Comment: @J.M. : This is not very satisfying...

Comment: Right, so I haven't written an answer yet @Patrick, and merely left it as a comment. I have to go to my lunch now, and maybe finish this later unless somebody can fill the gaps in my idea.

Comment: @Patrick: I beg to differ.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hint: 
$$
\sqrt t \int_1^\infty  {\frac{1}{{1 + tx^2 }}\,dx}  = \int_{\sqrt t }^\infty  {\frac{1}{{1 + x^2 }}\,dx}  \to \frac{\pi }{2}.
$$

Comment: @Shai, thank you. I tried this before I asked the question. But I failed to see that $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 0^{+}} |{\sum\limits_{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{t}}{1+tn^2}}-\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{\sqrt t }{{1 + tx^2 }}\,dx}|=0$. Now I could see that the difference is actually controlled by $\sqrt{t}$.

Answer (score 7):

Note the hyperbolic cotangent identity

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{z^2+n^2} =\frac{\pi z \coth(\pi z)-1}{2z^2}.$$

Replace $t$ with $t^2$ for convenience. Then

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{t}{1+t^2n^2} =\frac{1}{t}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{t^{-2}+n^2}=\frac{1}{2} \left[\pi\coth(\pi/t)-t\right].$$

Observe that $\coth(s)\to1$ as $s\to\infty$ and $t\to0$, so the limit is $\pi/2$.

Comment: J.M.: Seems my only real contribution was noticing $\coth \infty = 1$ ;)

Comment: In my defense, I was hungry while writing the comment to the question, and rumbling stomachs are distracting... :)

Comment: @Patrick: proving that partial fraction decomposition in here would require a bit of length, unfortunately... :P You might enjoy [this](http://books.google.com.ph/books?id=CC0dQxtYb6kC&pg=PA325); it should be nicely readable...

Comment: @J.M., this solution is eye-opening for me. Thanks!