# About this limit, $\lim_{t\to0^+} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt t}{1 + tn^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

This recent question, [Evaluating a limit, $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 0^{+}} {\sum\limits_{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{t}}{1+tn^2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/57970/11646), asked for the value of
$$\lim_{t\to0^+} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt t}{1 + tn^2}$$

So that I could better understand the answer can someone explain if this function of $t$ is discontinuous at $t=0$ and that is why the right-sided limit has to be taken? Does this function have any significance?

Comment: Questions should be self-contained...

Comment: Yes, the question should be rewritten. But the function is not continuous at $0$, because its value at $0$ is $0$, and the function tends to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as $t$ tends to 0 from above. For a function $f$ to be continuous at $a,$ we need $\lim_{t \to a} f(t) = f(a).$

Answer (score 7):

The function $\sqrt{t}$ is not defined for negative $t$. So it makes no sense to look at the behaviour as $t$ approaches $0$ through negative values.

The sum, as a function $F(t)$, can be expressed, for $t>0$, in terms of the hyperbolic cotangent of $\pi/\sqrt{t}$. For $t=0$, each term is $0$, so $F(0)=0$.

It was shown by @Shai Covo and @anon that $\lim_{t\to 0+}F(t)=\pi/2$.
So $F(t)$ is not continuous (from the right) at $t=0$.

However, if we *define* the function $G(t)$ by $G(t)=F(t)$ if $t>0$, and $G(0)=\pi/2$, then the function $G$ is continuous (from the right) at $t=0$.
This is because $\lim_{t\to 0+}F(t)=\pi/2$.

Of course $G(t)$ cannot be fully continuous at $0$, since we have not even *defined* it for negative $t$.  If we cared to, we *could* define $H(t)$ by $H(t)=G(t)$ if $t\ge 0$, and $H(t)=G(|t|)$ for $t<0$.  Then $H(t)$ would be continuous for all $t$.  This is not all that unreasonable.  Instead of summing $\sqrt{t}/(1+n^2 t)$, we would be summing $\sqrt{|t|}/(1+n^2 |t|)$.

The discontinuity (from the right)  of $F(t)$ at $t=0$ is in a sense not a mathematically significant one.  The technical term is that it is a [*removable* discontinuity.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities) The value of $F(0)$ is the "wrong one" for continuity from the right, but that can be easily changed by replacing that value by the "correct one," which should be $\pi/2$.

Comment: For negative $t$ the $\sqrt{t}$ can be understood as a complex number; more serious is the $1+ t n^2$ is the denominator, which makes the $n$th term undefined at $t = -1/n^2$.  These discontinuities are not removable.  The limit as $t \to 0-$ does not exist because there is no interval $(-\epsilon,0)$ on which your function is defined.

Answer (score 2):

The "significance" is that the sum is actually a Riemann sum that approximates the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$ with interval lengths $\sqrt{t}$.  Consequently as $t\to 0+$, the sum approaches the integral.

It is in fact discontinuous from the right.  If $t$ is actually equal to $0$, then the sum is exactly $0$, but as $t$ approaches $0$, the sum approaches $\pi/2$, not $0$.  That is a discontinuity.  But that does not explain why the limit is one-sided.  What one would do with $\sqrt{t}$ if $t$ were negative is not altogether clear, and at any rate a negative number cannot be the length of the intervals in a Riemann sum.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. Problems like this do occur in Cal I, II exercises disguised for Riemann integrals.

Comment: The Riemann sum, like the proper Riemann integral, require a finite domain of integration. Usually, the infinite domains work out, but it's nice to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

To make the notation simpler, substitute $t\mapsto t^2$:
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt t}{1+tn^2}
=\lim_{t\to0^+}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{t}{1+{(tn)^2}}
$$
First note that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=N/t}^\infty\frac{t}{1+{(tn)^2}}
&\le\frac1t\sum_{n=N/t+1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\\
&\le\frac1t\sum_{n=N/t+1}^\infty\frac1{n(n-1)}\\
&=\frac1N
\end{align}
$$
Since Riemann integrals are only over finite intervals, we need to restrict the sum to get the Riemann Sum (where $tn=x$ and $t=\mathrm{d}x$)
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to0^+}\sum_{n=1}^{N/t}\frac{t}{1+{(tn)^2}}
&=\int_0^N\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2}\\
&=\arctan(N)
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, letting $N\to\infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to0^+}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{t}{1+{(tn)^2}}
&=\arctan(N)+O\left(\frac1N\right)\\
&=\frac\pi2
\end{align}
$$

---

**Alternate approach**

Set $t=1/k$, then
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt t}{1+tn^2}
=\lim_{t\to0^+}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{t}{1+{(tn)^2}}
=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1/k}{1+{(n/k)^2}}
$$
Since $\frac{1/k}{1+{(n/k)^2}}$ is monotonically decreasing (in $n$), the [Integral Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) says
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2}
\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1/k}{1+{(n/k)^2}}
\le\int_{1/k}^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2}
$$
By the [Squeeze Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), we get
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1/k}{1+{(n/k)^2}}
=\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2}
=\frac\pi2
$$